# How do you update existing cell in a row in the MySQL table using PHP

Tags: php, html

I have MySQL Table that has two columns (name and description) in which I have already inserted some data using HTML Form.

However I'm trying to figure out if there is a way if a user enters existing name and different description so that it updates the description for that existing name instead of adding new row with existing name and new description.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset = "utf-8">
  <title>Search Results</title>
<style type = "text/css">
     body  { font-family: sans-serif; } 
     table { background-color: lightblue; 
             border-collapse: collapse; 
             border: 1px solid gray; }
     td    { padding: 5px; }
     tr:nth-child(odd) {
             background-color: white; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

        $db_connect = mysql_connect("hostname", "name", "password");
        $db_query = "SELECT * FROM urltable";

        // connect to MySQL
        if (!$db_connect)
        {
            die("Could not connect to database");
        }
        // open Products database
        if ( !mysql_select_db( "urls", $db_connect ) )
            die( "Could not open products database </body></html>" );

        $db_insert = "INSERT INTO urltable(URL, description) VALUES ('$URL', '$Description')";

        $db_insert_data = mysql_query($db_insert);

        if ($db_insert_data)
        {
            echo("<br>Input data is Added</br>");
        }
        else
        {
            echo("<br>Input data not Added</br>");
        }   

        // query Products database
        if ( !( $result = mysql_query( $db_query, $db_connect ) ) ) 
        {
            print( "<p>Could not execute query!</p>" );
            die( mysql_error() . "</body></html>" );
        } // end if

        mysql_close( $db_connect );

    ?><!-- end PHP script -->

     <table border="1">
        </br>
        <caption>URL TABLE</caption>
        </br>
        <?php

            // build table headings
            print( "<tr>" );
            print("<th>URL</th>");
            print("<th>Description</th>");
            print( "</tr>" );

            // fetch each record in result set
            while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $result ) )
            {
                // build table to display results
                print( "<tr>" );
                foreach ( $row as $value ) 
                    print( "<td>$value</td>" );
                print( "</tr>" );
            } // end while
        ?><!-- end PHP script -->
    </table>

    </br>
    <a href="insert.html">Home</a></br>

</body>
</html>
```

Right now it will just insert any data that is entered, but I can't figure out how to do the update on description only if the existing name is entered.  Could I use conditional statement to check for existing names?

Comment: Once you've got it working, fix the SQL injection bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use UPDATE.

```
"UPDATE tablename SET cloumnname = 'newname' WHERE ID = 'idoftheperson'"
```

and also do not use `mysql_query()` please use PDO library or mysqli.

here is a tutorial how you use UPDATE command in php.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

If you want to check database for exiting name or id you need to count data in mysql. for that do this please

```
            <?php
            /* Open a connection */
            $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

            /* check connection */
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                exit();
            }

            $query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER BY Name LIMIT 20";
            if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query)) {

                /* execute query */
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                /* store result */
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                 if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) >0){
                    /* do the mysql update here */
                 }

                /* close statement */
                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
            }

            /* close connection */
            mysqli_close($link);
            ?>
```

thanks

Comment: Query from your original post is working fine.  Also no need to worry about injection attacks, this will only run on localhost for like a week or two.  It will never go live.  Its jut for testing purposes.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You should look at the UPDATE command in MySQL.

Erdem's answer ***was*** an invalid query.

It should look something like this:

```
$db_update = "UPDATE urltable SET description = \"New description\" WHERE url = \"http://urlyouwanttoupdate.com\"";

mysql_query($db_update);
```

To add on what Joe said. For security purposes you can not allow your user's input directly into your query. This makes your database vulnerable to attacks known as "SQL Injections". Lots of content is already available online about this.

Here is a safe example for both the update and insert function you are using.

```
$safe_description = mysql_real_escape_string($Description);
$safe_url = mysql_real_escape_string($URL);

$db_update = "UPDATE urltable SET description=\"".$safe_description."\" WHERE url =\"".$safe_url."\"";
mysql_query($db_update);
```

For the safe insert:

```
$db_insert = "INSERT INTO urltable(URL, description) VALUES (\"".$safe_url."\", \"".$safe_description."\")";

$db_insert_data = mysql_query($db_insert);
```

Comment: my answer is right. and you should not use mysql_query anyway.

Comment: I see that you fixed it. You previously stated: "UPDATE tablename SET columnname = 'newname' WHERE = 'ID'.